# React JS bootstrap button limit on height and width

Tags: react-bootstrap

I wanted to create a circle button from react-bootstrap/Button but encountered a problem with its limit on how small a button is.

```
.circle-btn {
  width: .2vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid #9a9a9a 1px;
}

<Button className="circle-btn">
   a
</Button>
```

I wanted to create a small circle button with a on it's circle. My question is is there a limit on how small a react js bootstrap button?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit you can render is `1px` for both height & width for buttons. The same goes for `react-bootstrap` components, although overriding `CSS` should take place to achieve such limit.

See the little yellow dot in my example:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<button></button>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```